# How can i integrate plugin saml wso2is to magento?

Tags: magento, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've downloaded [this plugin](https://github.com/hukmedia/Magento-WSO2-SAML), but I don't know how to add it to Magento in order to reach SSO. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the configurations provided in the readme [1]. You can refer for more information on wso2 documentation [2]

[1] - https://github.com/hukmedia/Magento-WSO2-SAML/blob/master/Readme.md

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+a+Service+Provider